# Oracle SQL Load Variables from Config Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have added a procedure in a package (which is executed before the other ones) which reads variables from a configuration table with a select into structure for every variable to be read.

```
PROCEDURE load_config AS
BEGIN
    idproceduregeneral := utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram(utl_call_stack.subprogram(1));
    user_logs('Start', idproceduregeneral);
    SELECT
        week_offset,
        week_range
    INTO
        week_offset_ibsp,
        week_range_ibsp
    FROM
        dat_report_config
    WHERE
        process = 'EC'
        AND subprocess = 'IBSP';

-- Here I would do one select into for each of the variables I want to fetch.   

    days_offset_ibsp := week_offset_ibsp + week_range_ibsp * 7;
    days_offset_agencies := week_offset_agencies + week_range_agencies * 7;
    user_logs('Load Config', idproceduregeneral);
END load_config;
```

Is there any simple way of achieving this without having to select into for every single variable?

EDIT: this is how my config table would look like.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking.  You could, of course, write a single select statement that fetched multiple columns into multiple package variables.  Depending on what these variables represent, you could also declare a collection in your package instead of a bunch of local variables and fetch the data into that collection.  Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, it's hard to make suggestions.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch variable values from a config table. So far, I've been selecting one by one my variables as per the code. I was hoping for a more robust solution in case I have, let's say 20 variables to fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ROWTYPE` variable for this.

```sql
DECLARE
  config DAT_REPORT_CONFIG%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO config
    FROM dat_report_config
   WHERE process = 'EC'
     AND subprocess = 'IBSP';

   /*
    * Do what you gotta do. Now you can use your variables like this:
    * config.week_offset
    * config.week_range
    */
END;
```

For more info about `ROWTYPE` check the official documentation: [%ROWTYPE Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342)

Also, you can use a collection indexed by a `VARCHAR2` to load the variables for every subprocess and then access them by the subprocess name.

```sql
DECLARE
   TYPE type_configs IS TABLE OF DAT_REPORT_CONFIG%ROWTYPE INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
   configs TYPE_CONFIGS;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN ( SELECT *
                FROM dat_report_config
               WHERE process = 'EC' )
   LOOP
      configs(i.subprocess) := i;
   END LOOP;

   /*
    * Do what you gotta do. Now you can use your variables like this:
    * configs('IBSP').week_offset
    * configs('IBSP').week_range
    */
END;
```

More informations about collections here: [Working with Collections](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections).

This way works fine for little amount of data. But if your table has a lot of rows you will have performance issues. Cause this is referred as [“slow-by-slow processing.”](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall). I could not think of a way to do this using `SELECT BULK`, maybe someone else knows.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for. Is there any way to load everything at once (i.e. all subprocesses) and then access the associated week_offset/range by specifying alter on the subprocess?

Comment: I could not find a way to do this with a `SELECT` statement only. But I updated the answer to include a way to do this using collections indexed by `VARCHAR2`. If you could update your question to ask for this too it would be nice.